# Building Boost without filename decorations?

Tags: c++, boost

The default naming convention for the Boost C++ libraries is:

`libboost_regex-vc71-mt-d-1_34.lib`

where all libraries are built into the same directory. I'd like to modify the build process so that the filename does not contain the target architecture or build type (versions are okay). I want the file to end up in a different directory depending on the architecture being built for:

`vc71/debug/libboost-1_34.lib`

`vc71/release/libboost-1_34.lib`

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all decoration from the library filenames by passing "--layout=system". Your example above shows "vc71/release" paths -- there's no out-of-box way to get this layout. You can do that with a bit of hackign. In Jamroot, find the 'stage-proper' target, which specifies the location as:

```
  <location>$(stage-locate)/lib
```

You can modify that to specify different locations depending on properties, e.g:

```
  <variant>release:<location>$(stage-locate)/lib/release
  <variant>debug:<location>$(stage-locate)/lib/debug
```

Please see [Boost.Build website](http://boost.org/boost-build2) for more documentation

Comment: Where is --layout documented? I looked all over and I can't find any mention of it.

Comment: It's in the output of "bjam --help". Getting started refers to this options for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that with the Boost build system, but you could use a fairly simple script to move and rename them without too much difficulty.

On the other hand, with most Windows compilers, you seldom need to concern yourself with the library filenames because, for those libraries that require a separate binary, Boost employs [auto-linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-from-within-the-visual-studio-ide):

> Most Windows compilers and linkers have so-called “auto-linking support,” which eliminates the second challenge. Special code in Boost header files detects your compiler options and uses that information to encode the name of the correct library into your object files; the linker selects the library with that name from the directories you've told it to search.

Moving and renaming the files would break that.